# "Help me write this reminder email."

Tags: discussion

We get these like once a week. They are off-topic. They are too localized. Can we add this as a specific off-topic reason in the help tour or something? I feel like there has to be some way to let newbies know this in advance so we aren't constantly closing down first-time questions and/or first-time SE users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "what to write" close reason currently reads:

> This question appears to be off-topic because asking what to write or asking for help rephrasing a sentence or passage are both off-topic here, as such questions are very unlikely to help anybody else.

(There are links in there, but I didn't reconstruct them here.)

"Help me write X", where the OP is asking for text, seems to be a "what to write" question.

Based on a suggestion in a comment, I've modified the "what to writer" entry in the help center on-topic page.  This is in the "what **not** to ask" list:

> - Asking how to write a particular kind of email, letter, memo, or other correspondence -- or, more generally. asking "what should I write about" (more about this here).

Comment: What I'm looking for is something which can be read *before* the person posts something. In the help section there's the On-Topic part of the FAQ, which has a list of "don't ask these." (Questions seeking to interpret or analyze an existing work. Proofreading requests. *etc.*) I'm thinking more like adding **"How to write a particular kind of email, letter, memo, or other correspondence."**

Comment: @LaurenIpsum oh, I see!  Yes, that sounds like a good idea.  See my update.

Comment: if I may nitpick, can we split them up? I don't think someone who's never been here before will understand the difference, and they are both important. so: 
**[1]** • Asking how to write a particular kind of email, letter, memo, or other correspondence
**[2]** • Asking "what should I write about" (more about this here)

Comment: "What should I write about" can be homework, fiction, news, nonfiction, etc. That's a different kind of off-topic than "Help me write a reminder email."

Comment: @LaurenIpsum the list is already pretty long (too long IMO) at 8 bullets -- the *on-topic* list has only 6, for comparison.  Please take a look [in context](http://writers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) -- maybe you can suggest a reworking of that list that also incorporates this without expanding it even more?  If so, please propose it in an answer for better visibility.  Thanks!

Comment: I think you're right; it does work in context.